# Hot Reload not working in Visual Studio 17.7.4

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, hot-reload

I have a WPF project and Visual Studio is giving me a headache for several days now. Several days ago, I upgraded my Visual Studio version to 17.8.0 (I don't remember which previous version was though). At the same time I was upgrading the project from Target Framework 4.8 to 7.0. I got a lot of errors and I didn't know if it was because of the VS or the Target Framework issue so I downgraded VS version back to 17.7.4. Now the Hot Reload is not working! Before it can detects changes when I make changes in XAML file and save it but not it cannot.

I followed instructions on Microsoft documents but it still doesn't work. Is there any particular reason for this and anyway to fix it? If I have to, I think I can try upgrade VS again but I don't know if the Preview version is stable.

Here's the settings:

[image]

[image]